# Android 11 kotlin jetpack compose How to convert content Uri to FIle?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Here is my Code

```
 val launcher1 = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract =
            ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
                imageUri1 = uri
            }
```

And I must give to ViewModel Like this

```
fun deviceComplete(deviceId: Int?, file:File?) = viewModelScope.launch{
}
```

How to convert this uri to File ..?? I'm really don't know

Comment: plz don't answer me like -> File(imageUri1.path()) or File(imageUri1.toString())

Comment: One does not convert uries to file paths as one can use the uri directly.

Comment: val file = File(context.cacheDir,context.contentResolver.getFileName(uri = uri))

Answer (score 0):

This example for image Uri to File

`Application.instance` - this instance from Singleton Application Class

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
fun Uri.asFile(): File? {
    Application.instance.contentResolver
        .query(this, arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA), null, null, null)
        ?.use { cursor ->
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            val cursorData =
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA))

            return if (cursorData == null) {
                returnCursorData(this)?.let { File(it) }
            } else {
                File(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)))
            }
        }
    return null
}

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
private fun returnCursorData(uri: Uri?): String? {
    val context = Application.instance

    if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        val wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
        val splits = wholeID.split(":".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
        if (splits.size == 2) {
            val id = splits[1]
            val column = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
            val sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?"

            val cursor: Cursor? = context.contentResolver.query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                column, sel, arrayOf(id), null
            )

            val columnIndex: Int? = cursor?.getColumnIndex(column[0])
            if (cursor?.moveToFirst() == true) {
                return columnIndex?.let { cursor.getString(it) }
            }
            cursor?.close()
        }
    } else {
        return uri?.path
    }
    return null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you request permission first?

You can achieve that with

```
val state = rememberPermissionState(permission = Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

see more in: https://medium.com/compose-in-the-room/requesting-permissions-with-ease-in-jetpack-compose-using-accompanist-permissions-apis-76d5d9ca5f97